# css link hovered like the Playstation 4 user interface

Tags: javascript, css, html

Is there a way to create a glowing effect moving (as you can see on the video link when something is being hovered the glow goes up side down, becomes from intensive to less intensive) when link is hovered like the Playstation 4 user interface (see link below) with css?

Example of the effect on minute 0:26 on the video link below -->

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EkRIUxGFsSU

I can imagine this being done with css border glow using the border radius, box shadow and border properties. But how can I make the glowing move like the video link?. Heres an example I found on the css glowing border:

```
    .glowing-border {
        border: 2px solid #dadada;
        border-radius: 7px;
    }

    .glowing-border:focus { 
        outline: none;
        border-color: #9ecaed;
        box-shadow: 0 0 10px #9ecaed;
    }
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/CXUpm/1/show/
Click on the type field to see the glow.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that using CSS3 `transition`. With your example:

```
input {
    float:right;
    width:200px;
    border:2px solid #dadada;
    border-radius:7px;
    font-size:20px;
    padding:5px;
    margin-top:-10px;    
    transition: box-shadow 1s;
    box-shadow:0 0 0 #FF0000;
}

input:focus { 
    outline: 0 none;
    box-shadow:0 0 10px #FF0000;
}
```

This changes the box-shadow style on focus with a duration of 1 second.

[JSFiddle update](http://jsfiddle.net/CXUpm/1652/)

Comment: Thats not exactly what i was going for, but thanks for your effort. Im trying to make the border glow come and go and also make for example left border come on from the bottom to the top. I guess what im trying to make is perhaps a bit complex and it might work with svg animations

Comment: The come and go effect can be achieved through css animations, but the more complex effects are not exactly css friendly.. Perhaps you could make the left border go from bottom to the top by animating background-image, but I think it would be easier if you went with svg.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, i will try with svg